# Number of edges that can be removed from a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a connected graph with $e$ edges and $v$ vertices. I need to show that the maximal number of edges that can be removed so that the graph is still connected is $e-v+1$.

First attempt: Tried to do it by induction. In the case where $v=2$ we obviously can remove $e-1$ edges, and hence it is true that $e-v+1=e-1$ (replacing $v=2$ shows it is true). So then I supposed it was true for $n$ and tried to finish the proof but I am failing to see how can we use the inductive hypothesis.

Other attempt: Let us have $k$ vertices and begin with the first one, say $k_1$. Then if it is connected to say, other $m$ vertices, remove each edge that connects to some vertex more than once. Then move to any other vertex that is connected to the previous one and do the same thing again. Now for the next one, repeat and also remove any edge that connects you to the first vertex. For the fourth one the same, and so on until you go through all the vertices. Just did plenty of examples and it worked for all of them, but of course I would need some formal proof on this procedure.

How would you prove it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: for the induction: if a node has degree 1, you can remove it and the relative edge, falling into the previous case. Otherwise, all nodes have degree at least 2, so you can find a cycle

Comment: @paw88789 thank you, edited it.

Comment: @Exodd Ok so nodes = vertices, degree is the number of vertices to which a vertex is connected, but what are relative edges?

Comment: @Cedric Thank you; and consequently I deleted my comment!

Comment: @Cedric the edges relative to a vertex are the ones connected to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How would you prove it?

The following is a hint for formalizing your second method:

**HINT:** If $G$ is connected, the *minimal* connected subgraph (in terms of number of edges) of $G$ is its spanning tree. And a simple graph is a tree iff $e = v-1$.

Note also that trees have a property that removal of any edge makes them disconnected. This is what I meant by "minimal connected subgraph" above.

Comment: I like your answer. So it is pretty straightforward. We begin with a graph $G$, then remove the greatest number of edges such that it remains connected. It follows that the number of edges must be precisely $e=v-1$, since if it it is less then it must be disconnected, because an edge can at most connected two vertices at a time.

Comment: However if we have more edges, I am still sorting it out how to prove that we must be able to remove some. Just an update haha

Comment: "...if it it is less then it must be disconnected, because an edge can at most connected two vertices at a time." Here, the last reasoning is not really explaining why the trees are the minimal connected graphs. There are many definitions of trees in different sources so in order help you further, I should ask which definition of tree are you using.

Comment: I am using wikipedia's: A tree is an undirected graph in which any two vertices are connected by exactly one path.

Comment: Okay, then you need prove first that the definition you use implies removal of any edge in a tree makes it disconnected (this is the property I have written in my answer). I am leaving this as an exercise to you but if you have any problem proving, here is a routine proof of that statement: https://sharmaeklavya2.github.io/theoremdep/nodes/graph-theory/trees/deleting-edge-disconnects.html (I am not writing the proof myself because it is not really the focus of this question).

Comment: "However if we have more edges, I am still sorting it out how to prove that we must be able to remove some." And this will follow from the fact that every connected graph has a spanning tree. This statement can be proven by using induction on number of edges. And proving this actually gives you the idea how to remove the maximal number of edges. So it can improve your first method.